# Can I put scratch paper on my vermicompost?

Tags: compost, vermicomposting

I have lots of scratch paper here and am wondering if I should put it in my vermicompost or just throw it away.

1. Would it be dangerous for worms?
2. Will the soil benefit from it?

As for the type of worms that I'm using, I am still looking for the worms that I can buy so for now there's just a little amount of worms that I've randomly found on soil. I am in the Philippines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paper is just cellulose pulp. Woody stems are largely cellulose also. So putting scratch paper in you compost should be okay. Just as it is better to have small pieces of compostables, paper will compost faster if you can shred it or tear it into smaller pieces. But, even if you don't, it will be okay.

Comment: How about papers with inks, those brochures that has been heavily colored?

Comment: Stuff like newspapers are okay. The only thing that might be a problem is very shiny papers. These sometimes are impregnated with plastics that won't compost. I don't think any inks in use today are toxic, per SE.

Comment: There's a school of thought that the inks MAY contain noxious substances especially the coloured ones, but that will need be clarified. Organic books I've read don't recommend it.  I would have thought some/small amount of printed paper would be fine in amongst other things to rot down.  Do I understand you correctly that scratch paper is what I may know to be sand paper?

Comment: @Rosie oh, scratch paper is a used paper. A paper that has been used but are now no longer needed and is good for trash.

Comment: "Woody steems are largely cellulose also". Not exactly, up to 35 % of mass is lignin

Comment: @CaryBondoc For glossed/colored paper, it it doesn't mention being soy based, it's probably not and I'd stay away from using it.

Comment: I would be careful in how much shredded paper is added to the bin in proportion to the other bedding materials.  Certain materials like shredded paper don't remain "fluffy" and may get matted down causing anaerobic conditions.  I use a light amount on the top, but for bedding, I use very little.